# Conditional refreshing page - how to set a referrer?

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh my particular page, when referrer is blank. 
To do this I used this script:

```
 if (document.referrer === "" && document.URL.match("mysite.com/page1/module1")){
     window.location.reload();
 }
```

Of course it refreshes endlessly - because after refreshing the site the referrer is blank too.

How can make it to refresh only one time?

Comment: The "referrer" thing is terribly unreliable; there's really no reason to pay attention to it. It was a bad idea, never properly implemented.

Comment: Refresher is a bad idea , stay away

Comment: This sounds like an attempt to hack around poor cache control headers instead of addressing the root cause. That of course, is [only a guess](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: on refresh, alter the url slightly and avoid refresh when that alteration is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
top.location.href = top.location.href;
```

Instead of this:

```
window.location.reload();
```

And it's better to use PHP to make this condition:

```
<?php
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
   echo '<script>top.location.href = top.location.href;</script>';
}
?>
```

Anyway what you are trying to do is very bad practice, because many people are blocking browser to send referers.