# Javascript: compare previous url with current one

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Requirement:

Compare the previous url with the current one and do some action.

---

#### Problem:

The `document.referrer` is still same after the page refresh.

---

#### Question:

Is there an elegant way of comparing urls other then storing a cookie or session?

Comment: No comment on downvote? :)

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039019/conditional-refreshing-page-how-to-set-a-referrer

Comment: @HappyHamburger I don't see how it might help? Can you light me up?

Comment: Sorry I was implying to stay away from that. JavaScript never does anything in an 'elegant' way. It's going to be tricky generally just using javascript, especially if you are expecting this to not  change after a page refresh. I suggest doing this using something like php or python, depending on what you are using, if you want to stay away from cookies or local storage.

Comment: Got it :) you can add your latest comment as an answer and I will accept it. I think I will go with local storage and set the current url with `onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript never does anything in an 'elegant' way. It's going to be tricky generally just using javascript, especially if you are expecting this to not change after a page refresh.

While I would suggest either cookies or local storage, your other alternative is saving the "state" of the page using a back-end programming language.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone will be interested how I resolved my problem:

```
// store the current url
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("current-url", window.location.href);
};

// read
var urlReferrer = window.localStorage.getItem("current-url");

// do something
if (urlReferrer != window.location.href)
```